# iOS SwiftUI - View closes after changing @AppStorage value

Tags: swiftui

I'm absolute beginner in iOS development and I'm wondering why nobody else faced this issue because I can't find similar question.

At the beginning I'm declaring:

```
@AppStorage("userid") var userid: Int = 0
```

then couple lines of code down below:

```
if(userid == 0){

    NavigationLink(destination: Login(), label: {
        Image(systemName: "person.circle.fill")
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit).frame(width: 32)
            .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor(named: "IconColor")!))
    })

}else{
    
    NavigationLink(destination: Login(), label: {
        Image(systemName: "person.circle.fill")
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit).frame(width: 32)
            .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
    })
    
}
```

in the `Login()` view:

```
struct Login: View {
    @AppStorage("userid") var userid: Int = 0

    var body: some View{
        
        Button(action: {
                                    
            if(userid == 0){
                userid = 1
            }else{
                userid = 0
            }
            
        }) {
            Text("weird")
        }
    }
}
```

After taping on `weird`, `Login()` closes and I see the icon color changing which means `@AppStorage` value changed.

But why does the view closes on changing a `@AppStorage` value??

Comment: It closes because your `NavigationLink` is inside an `if` clause. When the condition changes, the result of the link disappears with the link. It looks like you should have *one* `NavigationLink` with a conditional statement within the `foregroundColor`: `.foregroundColor(userid == 0 ?  Color(UIColor(named: "IconColor")!) : .blue)`

Comment: @jnpdx But what if want the destination also be different depending on userid? Or maybe not having a NavigationLink at all when userid is 0, will I have to face new surprises after changing userid 1 to 0 in another View? And i thought iOS development is a blessing compared to android first, but nooo here comes all kind of new crap

Comment: @jnpdx well thanks, I'll accept if you explain this in an answer

Comment: As to your first comment, there are plenty of solutions possible, such as a `NavigationLink` in the background that is hidden, using one page that displays different information conditionally depending on the state, etc. But, I can really only answer the question as laid out in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It closes because your `NavigationLink` is inside an `if` clause. When the condition changes, the result of the link disappears with the link.

It looks like you should have one `NavigationLink` with a conditional statement within the `foregroundColor`:

```
.foregroundColor(userid == 0 ?  Color(UIColor(named: "IconColor")!) : .blue)
```